# mySQL ORDER BY in joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, filesort

Ok, so i have the following schema and query which is very slow (when using real data) because of the ORDER BY:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e7bb/10

As per mysql man : "You are joining many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows. (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a const join type.) "

but i still need to sort by that column. How would i need to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** since the fiddle was updated :

```
SELECT
    cpa.product_id, 
    cp.product_internal_ref, 
    cp.product_name, 
    cpa.product_sale_price, 
    cpa.is_product_service, 
    cpa.product_service_price
FROM 
    catalog_products_attributes cpa
JOIN
    catalog_products cp ON cp.product_id = cpa.product_id 
WHERE
    cpa.product_id IN (
        SELECT
            product_id
        FROM 
            catalog_products_categories
        WHERE
            category_id = 41 
    )
ORDER BY 
    cpa.product_service_price DESC
```

Comment: Also, i tried your query and is 2x slower then what i had... :(

Comment: I just modified the fiddle, please take a look. Using your sollution does improove performance A LOT. But i wonder if there are other ways to do this without derived tables. Thank you    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e7bb/10

Comment: I also looked over the query you updated but that uses a DEPENDENT SUBQUERY which kills performance (i tested with real data)

Comment: what were the benchmark results ? you could add a index on `category_id`(this will be used for filtering) and `cpa.product_service_price` (this will be used for sorting)

Comment: category_id has an index already but after adding an index on product_service_price things got faster : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0874f/1

Comment: as expected :) so did you benchmark the 2 queries to see which is fastest ?

Comment: query against 80k rows with 1st query i got a 0,323 sec and 0,016 sec with second query heh...

Comment: what was the second query? also i assume you use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to be sure the results are not taken from cache

Comment: second query, the one with the dependent subquery. and yes i use SQL_NO_CACHE